# Что за тип в аргументе конструктора?

Tags: php

```
public function __construct(\DateTimeImmutable ...$dates)
```

что за запись такая? и с какой версии php работает?

по логите это типизированный (из DateTimeImmutable ) массив.

но если вызвать конструктор так:

```
$new = new Entity([new \DateTimeImmutable]);
```

то ошибка несоответствия типов.

Comment: `$new = new Entity(new \DateTimeImmutable);` ?

Comment: @splash58 `...$dates` ни о чем не говорит?

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e0c3e95589e8f73ccb37b7720766d1ae771fdcf6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно выводит, потому что на вход должен приходить объект, а приходит массив. 
Такая запись эквивалентна этой (пример):

```
function myFunc(int ...$ints) {
    var_dump($ints);
}

myFunc(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

То есть, все аргументы функции будут в переменной `$ints` в виде массива, но должны иметь тип `integer`

В вашем случае:

```
$new = new Entity(new \DateTimeImmutable, new \DateTimeImmutable, new \DateTimeImmutable);
```

внутри функции будет доступен массив `$dates` значения которого объекты класса `DateTimeImmutable`

Данная запись называется уточнение типа `funcName(\DateTimeImmutable $var)`